# Explain Dart Mixin declaration

Tags: dart

Can anyone help me understand this piece of code?

```
@immutable
abstract class User with _$User {
  const factory User(String name, int age) = _User;
}
```

The syntax I particularly want to understand is the benefit for the class to mixin itself apparently and what the prefix _$ means in the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see you most likely dealing with class that will have more code generated using code generator.
Class **User** does not mixin itself. It mixins class ***$User***. Class **$User** will be generated and placed in appropriate *.g.dart file which will be part of your *.dart file once code generator is complete.